# www.googleapis.com geolocation failure

Tags: google-cloud-platform, geolocation

I'm using various things on GCP APIs and the gelocation for www.googleapis.com appears to be wrong:

```
PING www.googleapis.com (172.217.169.138) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from sof02s32-in-f10.1e100.net (172.217.169.138): icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=112 ms
^C
--- www.googleapis.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 112.008/112.008/112.008/0.000 ms
```

```
138.169.217.172.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer sof02s32-in-f10.1e100.net.
```

Which is Sofia, Bulgaria and I'm in New York.

Any idea how to reach someone inside the google cloud team who can assist?

Comment: `172.217.12.138` is not `Sofia, Bulgaria` it's in NYC

Comment: Hi Adam. What output do you get when you run this command:

dig -t TXT o-o.myaddr.google.com

Comment: @MikeSchwartz 199.66.200.5

Comment: @alexus where are you getting `172.217.12.138` from ?

Comment: @AdamJacobMuller sorry, when I tried to resolve `www.googleapis.com` I got that IP, I just did it again and I got another IP address again.

Answer (score 0):

This topic of Google IP address geolocation has been covered numerous times on Stackoverflow.

**You cannot reliably use geolocation for Google IP addresses.** They are registered to a Google business address and not to datacenters. Some Google IP addresses are global and are located at more than one datacenter at the same time. Google implements Software Defined Networking (SDN). IP addresses can be relocated to a different location via software.

Additionally, Google does not publish this information, so your geolocation software/service is just making assumptions that might be valid at this point in time and invalid tomorrow.